# WSDL different from Schema

Tags: wsdl, xsd

I have developed a web service for send emails. I also created a schema that i could send to parts of the business to obviously tell them how they can use the service. This specifies minOccurs etc as a schema normally does. But if you go to the url of the web service and navigate to the WSDL using the url and ?wsdl, then this specifies different minOccurs, actually it just specifies the default.

My question is, how do i relate the schema to the WSDL??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe my answer is outdated, but I will try to answer your question.

There are few points that you need to have answered first.
1. What is your approach towards *WebServices*?
   **ContractFirst** / **ContractLast**?

If **ContractFirst** approach you should specify this in your *XSD (XML Schema)* file for the particular request / element. And if you use i.e. *Spring-WS framework* for generating *WSDL files*, it will generate correct WSDL for you based on XSD specification.

Otherwise (**ContractLast**) you should set it in your contracts & elements that are being used. And the framework should generate the WS for you based on the aforementioned information.

1. The thing is I do not really now which **tool** you use for WSDL generation. You might create it by hand, or generate it. That is where framework/platform comes into play.

Hope it helped.

Jan